# CompilationAction in Roslyn Analyzer not running on dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have created dotnet roslyn analyzer which run on compilation.

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("MicrosoftCodeAnalysisCorrectness", "RS1026:Enable concurrent execution", Justification = "<Pending>")]
        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
       context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);

            context.RegisterCompilationAction(AnalyzeCompilation);
        }
```

I added it as a package to one of our projects, it didn't run.
I figured that i need to allow Entire Solution Analysis in VS2022.
Tools => Options => Text Editor => c# => Analysis => Entire Solution

[Visual Studio Entire Solution Analysis feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUXaw.png)

After i allowed it, my analyzer working correctly.

I also want it to run in our pipeline, but the analyzer not running on **dotnet build** .
I am not sure if it's related to Entire Solution which i allowed in VS2022 or not.
we have other analyzer which running correctly on dotnet build.
this is how our Directory.BUild.props file looks.

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" Version="16.10.56">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers working on dotnet build.
How can i enable my Analyzer which run on ComplilationAction to work on dotnet build like it working in VS2022?